# Modifying destination and filename of gulp-svg-sprite

Tags: svg, gulp

I need to change the directory that the sprite files are compiled to.

I'm just trying to wrap my head around [gulp-svg-sprite](https://github.com/jkphl/gulp-svg-sprite) for the first time.  The goal is to have the `scss` file included in my `sass` directory, and then compiled with the rest of my partials - this part works fine.  However, the generated `svg` directory is also put into the `sass` directory, so I end up with:

```
- theme
-- sass
---- _sprites.scss
---- svg
------ sprite.css-58jkdf8js.svg
-- css
---- styles.css
```

When I actually need this:

```
- theme
-- sass
---- _sprites.scss    
-- css
---- styles.css
---- svg
------ sprite.css-58jkdf8js.svg
```

Of course, the compile stylesheet has `background: url(svg/sprite.css-58adlksjf.svg);`

**How can I make that sprite directory get compiled under `/css` instead of `/sass`?**

This is the relevant part of `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('svg', function() {

  config                  = {
    mode                : {
        css             : {     // Activate the «css» mode
            render      : {
              scss      : true  // Activate CSS output (with default options)
            },
            dest        : './',            
            cssFile     : "_sprite.scss"
        },
        symbol          : {
            dest        : '../css/'
        }
    }
};

  gulp.src('src/svg/*.svg')
    .pipe(svgSprite(config))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('sass'));
})
```

I only added in the `symbol` mode because I was hoping I could just make another copy there, but it just stores it as `sprite.symbol.svg` which is not what the CSS is referencing.

I'm thinking an alternative is to forget about `sass` for the svg stuff, compile it to `/css` and then include another stylesheet.  However, that means I would have to include it *before* the main stylesheet (which right now seems ok, but I haven't thought that part through yet).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I understand it might be too late but my solution was something like this:

```
gulp.task('svg', function() {
    var config = {
        dest : '.',
        mode : {
             css : {
                 dest : '.',
                 sprite : 'css/svg/sprite.svg',
                 render : {
                     css : {dest : 'css/sprite.css'},
                     scss : {
                         dest : './sass/_sprite.scss'
                     }
                 },
             }
         }
     };
 gulp.src('src/svg/*.svg')
     .pipe(svgSprite(config))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
})
```

I prefer to specify

```
  config.dest : '.'
```

even it's default, and also to leave

```
gulp.dest('.')
```

and handle the folder from config.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably too late for your problem, but in the meantime there's an extra section about [output destinations](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite/#output-destinations) in the svg-sprite docs (because it's definitely not trivial). An important thing to understand is that the several `dest` options work relative to each other (as long as you don't use absolute paths).

- `config.dest` specifies a main output directory used as the base for all output modes.
- `config.<mode>.dest` is relative to `config.dest` and is used as main output destination for the current mode.
- `config.<mode>.render.<format>.dest` (if given) is again relative to `config.<mode>.dest` and is used as output path and file name for the specified `<type>` files. It defaults to `"sprite.<format>"`.
- `config.<mode>.sprite` specifies the name and location of the sprite relative to `config.<mode>.dest`.

So by default the two CSS sprite modes `"css"` and `"view"` will render their stylesheets to

```
config.dest + config.<mode>.dest + "sprite.<format>"
```

while the SVG sprite itself will be created at

```
config.dest + config.<mode>.dest + config.<mode>.sprite
```

The relative path used for referencing the sprite from within the stylesheet will be derived automatically from these two locations.

Now, when you use the Sass output format, you introduce a compilation step that *svg-sprite* has no control over. The only thing *svg-sprite* knows is that your **final compiled CSS** is supposed to be found at `config.dest + config.<mode>.dest + "sprite.<format>"` (or whatever you configured for `config.<mode>.render.css.dest` in particular). You just need to ensure that your Sass compilation result really lands there an you will be all set.

---

Having said all that, in your particular situation, your configuration should look like this (off the top of my head):

```
var config                  = {
    "dest"                  : "theme",
    "mode"                  : {
        "css"               : {
            "render"        : {
                "scss"      : {
                    "dest"  : "../sass/_sprites.scss"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this didn't only help solving your particular problem but also clear things up a little in general. You might also always consider using the [online configuration kickstarter](http://jkphl.github.io/svg-sprite) to get off the ground quickly.

Comment: How do I set my custom mustache template? It's fairly useless without this possibility.

Comment: @actimel The custom template can be set via `mode.css.render.scss.template` (for the example above). Please find all information about [rendering configurations in the docs](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#rendering-configurations). You might also be interested in the [online configurator](http://jkphl.github.io/svg-sprite) to ease up configuration.

Comment: Well the documentation is so hard to read that i didn't find this option. Thank you.