# How to configure gulp-svg-sprite for this destination?

Tags: svg, gulp, development-environment, svg-sprite

**gul-svg-sprite 1.2.19**

I'm having a lot of trouble with the config object that is passed to gulp-svg-sprite to determine the destination of the files created.  I have read the doc section on [output destination](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite/#output-destinations) and read through this other [StackOverflow board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838150/modifying-destination-and-filename-of-gulp-svg-sprite) on the matter.

**Here is the Gulp task:**

```
gulp.task('build-icons',function(){
    return gulp.src(assetsDev+'icons/*.svg')
        .pipe(svgSprite({
            mode: {defs:true, dest:'.'},
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('icons'));
});
```

**This is what I'm hoping to get:**

```
icons
---sprite.defs.svg
```

**Instead this is what I get:**

```
icons
---defs
------svg
---------sprite.defs.svg
```

I'm tried changing the value of mode.dest, or adding a "dest" setting as a sibling to "mode" but it makes no difference.  Basically, no matter what I write, the file is always saved in the same location.  I think my setting is just ignored. For instance if I add sprite:"mysprite.svg" to the mode settings, the file is still saved as "sprite.defs.svg" in the same location.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

A solution was posted at https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite/issues/155

Basically my mistake was that I was trying to configure destination in an object sibling to `defs`, instead of configuring the destination within the `defs` object itself. the correct configuration object for my purpose should be changed from:

```
mode: {defs:true, dest:'.'}
```

to:

```
mode: {defs:{dest:'.'}}
```

The produced file is now saved in the `icons` folder as I wished.